# Can I convert an ext3 partition into ext4 without formatting?

Tags: filesystems, partition, ext4

my home directory is on a separate partition which still uses ext3. Is there a way to convert this partition into ext4 in a non-destructive way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can. This is explained very nicely in [the ext4-wiki at kernel.org](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Howto#Converting_an_ext3_filesystem_to_ext4). Basically it all boils down to

```
tune2fs -O extents,uninit_bg,dir_index /dev/DEV
e2fsck -fDC0 /dev/DEV
```

with /dev/DEV replaced by the partition in question. Although this should be non-destructive, I'd still strongly suggest to back up your data before doing it.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this will not automagically convert existing files to use extents for example.

Comment: I cannot express strongly enough how important it is to backup your data before doing a transformation like this.